# LUB of Seq and Set

Tags: scala

I took the Least Upper Bound of a `Seq` and `Set`:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> lub( List (typeOf[Seq[_]], typeOf[Set[_]]) )
res12: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = 
             Iterable[Any] with Int with _$2 => Any forSome { type _$2 }
```

Please help me understand the output. I'm guessing that the `Iterable` is the least parent of `Set` and `Seq`.

But what about the rest?

Answer (score 1):

The `(Int with _$2) => Any forSome { type _$2 }` part comes from the fact that both extend `Function1` (`Set` directly, and `Seq` by extending `PartialFunction`).

Specifically it's the LUB of `(A) => Boolean` (extended by `Set[A]`) and `PartialFunction[Int, A]` (extended by `Seq[A]`).

```
@ import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

@ lub(List(typeOf[Function1[_, Boolean]], typeOf[PartialFunction[Int, _]]))
res1: Type = _$1 with Int => Any forSome { type _$1 }
```

where

`Int with _` is the GLB of `Int` and `_` (since the first type argument of `Function1` is contravariant)

and

`Any` is the LUB of `_` and `Boolean`.